# htaccess that grabs additional parameters and pass them to redirection point

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hey there i already have quite a few rewriting working on a project, but now i would like to be able to pass additional parameters to the main access point

my htaccess is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$                        index.php  [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ index.php?account=$1&task=$2&object_id=$3&app_type=$4&p=$5&items=$6
```

What i would like is to be able to pass additional parameters and those parameters should be rewrited and passed to index.php in addition to the original parameters like in:

```
http://site.com/user/books/434?another_param=8989898
```

and that should rewrite to index.php accordingly as in:

```
index.php?account=user&task=books&object_id=434&app_type=&p=&items=&another_param=8989898
```

What modification must me made to .htaccess in order to rewrite those additional parameters and append them to the original redirection being made?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lawrence Cherone just said it. Check out documentation if you want more information http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dead simple, add the "Query-String-Append" flag to the rewriteRule, the format is:

```
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]
```

(source) http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

The flag for query-string-append is simply **QSA**, so in your example you would have:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ index.php?account=$1&task=$2&object_id=$3&app_type=$4&p=$5&items=$6 [QSA]
```

Another useful flag for you would be **L** which means "Last" ie, apache stops looking for more matches after it's performed the substitution:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ index.php?account=$1&task=$2&object_id=$3&app_type=$4&p=$5&items=$6 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the QueryStringAppend [QSA] flag eg:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```